# Spring - Pessimistic Lock implementation

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to introduce Pessimistic Locking in a method in my Spring application, with no success. I'm using Spring and Hibernate, with MySQL db
I have this controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sensoristica")
    public ResponseEntity<Sensoristica> findIlluminazione(@RequestParam(value = "idLuce") int idLuce,
            @RequestParam(value = "lit") boolean lit, @RequestParam(value = "suServer") boolean suServer) {

        Luce luce = luceService.findById(idLuce);
        int idInterruttore = luce.getInterruttore().getIdInterruttore();
        if (luce.isAttivo()) {
            int timeout = luce.getTimeout();
            Date date = new Date();
            Date dateTime = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
            // aggiorniamo lo stato del sensore
            luce.setDateTime(dateTime);
            luce.setLit(lit);
            if (lit) { 
                Interruttore interruttore = interruttoreService.findById(idInterruttore);
                interruttoreService.pushTimeout(interruttore, timeout);
            }

        } else {
            logger.debug("Sensore " + idLuce + " non attivo");
            luce.setLit(false);
        }

        luceService.updateLuce(luce);
        return new ResponseEntity<Sensoristica>(sensoristica, HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

The `pushTimeout(interruttore, timeout)` is in a service class and it's

```
@Override
    @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)
    public void pushTimeout(Interruttore interruttore, int timeout) {
        try {
        Date nextTimeout = interruttore.getTimeoutDate();
        DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        Date richiesta = dt.plusMinutes(timeout).toDate();
        DateTimeComparator comparator = DateTimeComparator.getInstance(DateTimeFieldType.secondOfMinute());
        int toUpdate = comparator.compare(nextTimeout, richiesta);
        if (toUpdate < 0) { 
            interruttore.setTimeoutDate(richiesta);
            updateInterruttore(interruttore);
            logger.debug("new Timeout: " + richiesta);
        } else {
            logger.debug("Timeout previous or equal, don't update");
        }
        } catch (PessimisticLockingFailureException pe){
            logger.error("Pessimistic lock error", pe);
        }

    }
```

When multiple requests arrive to my controller I'd expect that only the first will arrive to `pushTimeout` and the other get the exception, but it's not... for instance look at the logs:

```
2016-11-04 19:03:57 DEBUG InterruttoreServiceImpl:136 - new Timeout: Fri Nov 04 19:04:57 CET 2016
2016-11-04 19:03:58 DEBUG InterruttoreServiceImpl:136 - new Timeout: Fri Nov 04 19:04:58 CET 2016
2016-11-04 19:03:58 DEBUG InterruttoreServiceImpl:136 - new Timeout: Fri Nov 04 19:04:58 CET 2016
2016-11-04 19:03:58 DEBUG InterruttoreServiceImpl:136 - new Timeout: Fri Nov 04 19:04:58 CET 2016
2016-11-04 19:03:58 DEBUG InterruttoreServiceImpl:136 - new Timeout: Fri Nov 04 19:04:58 CET 2016
2016-11-04 19:03:58 DEBUG InterruttoreServiceImpl:136 - new Timeout: Fri Nov 04 19:04:58 CET 2016
```